# How to include gems in compiled macruby apps?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, macruby

I have a simple ruby script, which I compile to a standalone Mac app with macruby (with macruby dylib bundled etc).

Recently I've added a require for `digest/sha1`, and I've noticed that after this the compiled app doesn't work on machines that don't have MacRuby installed. (i get a `no such file to load -- digest/sha1 (LoadError)`
Is there a way to bundle the internal `digest` gem to the compiled app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use macruby_deploy on the app bundle like so:
`macruby_deploy --embed /path/to/bundle.app`

It will embed the entire framework.